# Pandas transpose by columns and index

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a dataFrame as:

```
df=
     field_1       field_2
 10  123             456  
 20  789             101112
 30  131415          161718
```

I want something like that:

```
index   field   value
 10    field_1    123
 10    field_2    456 
 20    field_1    789
 20    field_2    101112
 30    field_1    131415
 30    field_2    161718
```

I tried to transpose the dataFrame but is not the same.
I can't see any solution except interact row by row and save in a new dataFrame.

Comment: did you try with  melt

Comment: @BENY '.stack()' work perfectly. I didn't know about this function. Thanks!